# Database not written to when relationship edited from the inverse side on a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: jpa, orm, eclipselink, persistence, java-ee-7

JPA Provider is EclipseLink. Having the following entities:

```java
@Entity
class Symptom {

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "symptoms")
    private Set<Disorder> disorders;
}

@Entity
class Disorder {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "disorder_symptoms")
    private Set<Symptom> symptoms;
}
```

One symptom can be found on many disorders and many disorders can have many symptoms. `Symptom` is defined as the inverse (non-owning) side of the relationship, but this being a bidirectional relationship, it shouldn't matter.

When i add a new symptom to `Disorder`, database table `disorder_symptoms` is updated as expected. But when i add a disorder to `Symptom`, the table is not populated. Tried with `cascade` attribute set for either side, still no result.

Is there something wrong i'm doing here?

Comment: "but this being a bidirectional relationship, it shouldn't matter." Why would you say that? Bidirectional relationships require YOU update both sides to keep them in sync with what you want in the database, but only changes to the owning side affect what is in the database. Ensure you set both sides and that the Disorder you want pointing at the Symptom is correctly merged into the persistence unit for the changes to get picked up.

Comment: @Chris, reason being there's a single source of truth - that one table. What is your opinion on making both sides the owning side - same @JointTable(name="...") and remove the `mappedBy` attribute? When i tried it in various use cases, my provider doesn't complain and i get desired behavior.

Comment: Provider will care as it will mean you have two writable mappings intended to control the same foreign key column, intentionally to allow them to be different and out of sync wth each other. It may work, but only until it doesn’t in seemingly strange situations. If you are going to change only one side, maintain the owning side or make it unidirectional.